# iOS: Standard architectures enabled but iTunes not recognising 64 bit support

Tags: objective-c, xcode, itunes, arm64

I have the following settings in my app to support 64 bit architectures but when I submit to app store for beta testing it gives me an error that your app is not supporting 64 bit. What could be the reason for it?
[image: active]

Comment: Are you using any libraries without a 64 bit version?

Answer (score 0):

Try again by doing a

1-Clean (Frist)
2-Build (Second)
3-Archive (Third)

This could be the solution!