# Xcode Missing 64-bit support with standard architectures enabled

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, 64-bit, app-store-connect

I have looked through several similar questions and am still unable to get it to work. When I archive and upload my app to the app store, I get the error message :

> iTunes Store operation failed. Missing 64-bit support. Starting
>   February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include
>   64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or
>   later. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the
>   default Xcode build setting of "Standard architectures" to build a
>   single binary with both 32-bit and 64-...

[image: Error message]

As suggested in other questions/answers, I have brought my app up to recommended settings, set Standard Architectures and Valid Architectures to include arm64 (See below)
[image: Standard Architectures]

This did not work, I received the same error message when I tried to upload the app. I don't have any iOS devices connected to my machine while doing this. I also read that some 3rd party libraries may cause this, but I believe the only 3rd party libraries I use are Google Analytics and Google Mobile Ads, both of which I updated recently (I even tried removing Google Analytics but that did not work either). See the linked libraries section:
[image: Linked libraries]

After doing all of this, I am at a loss as to why the error message still comes up. I also tried deleting the Derived Data. Is there some other setting in one of the classes that could block the app from supporting 64-bit? How do I get this app to support 64-bit?

Questions/answers I tried previously:

[iOS app: Missing 64-bit support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29655116/ios-app-missing-64-bit-support)

[iOS: Standard architectures enabled but iTunes not recognising 64 bit support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30603698/ios-standard-architectures-enabled-but-itunes-not-recognising-64-bit-support)

[iOS app submission : missing 64-bit support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support)

[Why the Missing 64-bit support happened when upload to the iTunes connect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28312779/why-the-missing-64-bit-support-happened-when-upload-to-the-itunes-connect)

Comment: what's your OS and Xcode versions?

Comment: In my case a restart of Xcode did it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To enable 64-bit support:

You need to add "arm64" under "Valid Architectures" and set "Architecture" as "Standard Architecture" as shown in attached screenshot.

Also make sure to turn "Build Active Architectures Only" to NO.

[image: To enable 64-bit support]

Comment: Thank you. This one is technically the better answer. I misspelled "arm64" as "armv64". Fixing this made the app work

Comment: in my case Build Active Arch Only was Yes. I changed it to No and it works

Comment: life saver !  such an arcane pos that sw.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually add 64- bit (arm64) support like this:[image]